# Polars python .list.concat behaviour for column dtype List[str]

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to concat a fixed list of string to the polars dataframe column of data type `List[str]` but the behaviour is different from `List[i64]`.

Here is the sample.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"libs": [["aa", "bb", "cc",], ["aa", "bb", "cc",]]})
```

```
# Output:

shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────┐
│ libs               │
│ ---                │
│ list[str]          │
╞════════════════════╡
│ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] │
│ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] │
└────────────────────┘
```

Following code works:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("libs").list.concat([pl.lit("dd"), pl.lit("ee")]))

# Output

shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────────────────┐
│ libs                 │
│ ---                  │
│ list[str]            │
╞══════════════════════╡
│ ["aa", "bb", … "ee"] │
│ ["aa", "bb", … "ee"] │
└──────────────────────┘
```

But following code throws error (same would work for numeric list):

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("libs").list.concat(["dd", "ee"]))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ColumnNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 df.with_columns(pl.col("libs").list.concat(["dd", "ee"]))

File ~/.virtualenvs/utilities-3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:7260, in DataFrame.with_columns(self, exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
   7108 def with_columns(
   7109     self,
   7110     exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr] | None = None,
   7111     *more_exprs: IntoExpr,
   7112     **named_exprs: IntoExpr,
   7113 ) -> DataFrame:
   7114     """
   7115     Add columns to this DataFrame.
   7116 
   (...)
   7255 
   7256     """
   7257     return (
   7258         self.lazy()
   7259         .with_columns(exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
-> 7260         .collect(no_optimization=True)
   7261     )

File ~/.virtualenvs/utilities-3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1501, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, common_subplan_elimination, streaming)
   1490     common_subplan_elimination = False
   1492 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1493     type_coercion,
   1494     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1499     streaming,
   1500 )
-> 1501 return wrap_df(ldf.collect())

ColumnNotFoundError: dd

Error originated just after this operation:
DF ["libs"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

Mey be when I pass list of string to `concat` method, it is expected to be the column name(s). Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Wrapping the whole list should work:`pl.lit([ .... ])` e.g. `.concat(pl.lit(["dd", "ee"]))` - but yeah, strings are used as column name lookups e.g. `df.with_columns(x = "libs")`

Comment: @jqurious wrapping list with `pl.lit` has different behaviour. In this case output of `to_dicts()` is `[{'libs': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']}, {'libs': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'ee']}]`

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant: `pl.lit( [ ["dd", "ee"] ] )`

Comment: You could also do a list comprehension `[pl.lit(x) for x in  ["dd", "ee"]]`

Answer (score 1):

strings are used for column name lookups, which is why this works:

```
# newlibs = pl.col("libs")

df.with_columns(newlibs = "libs")
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ libs               ┆ newlibs            │
│ ---                ┆ ---                │
│ list[str]          ┆ list[str]          │
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] ┆ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] │
│ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] ┆ ["aa", "bb", "cc"] │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

You can do the following:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("libs").list.concat(pl.lit([["dd", "ee"]]))
).to_dicts()
```

```
[{'libs': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']},
 {'libs': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']}]
```

It may help to read it as: `pl.lit([strings])` instead of `[[]]`

The reason for the outer brackets is the difference between:

```
pl.Series([["dd", "ee"]])

# shape: (1,)
# Series: '' [list[str]]
# [
#   ["dd", "ee"]
# ]
```

and:

```
pl.Series(["dd", "ee"])

# shape: (2,)
# Series: '' [str]
# [
#   "dd"
#   "ee"
# ]
```

Without them you're not creating a list type.